# Visual Studio, localizing a ribbon item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ribbon, visual-studio-addins

In Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, whenever I change the language from '(Default)' to something else in the properties of a ribbon item in a Word 2010/2013 add-in project in C#, I get these two errors:

For every item that has been set using Factory.CreateItem() (like Factory.CreateRibbonDialogLauncher()):

> The type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Ribbon.View.GenericRibbonView'
>   has no property named 'Factory'. Call stack: at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyReferenceExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodePropertyReferenceExpression propertyReferenceEx, Boolean
>   reportError) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, Object codeObject) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)

For every tab in the ribbon:

> The variable 'tab1' is either undeclared or was never assigned. Call
>   stack:
>   at
>    System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

The project is new, the only thing I did was add a ribbon item.

What's the problem?